# Async setTimeout blocks express processing until res.send happens

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an async operation that gets delegated to a worker process.

Since each operation takes roughly 2 seconds, I wanted to pass the result of that operation in the request response.

I've wrapped the execution of the worker process in a promise, which does not resolve until the worker process finishes the CPU intensive job and returns a result:

```
module.exports = (req, res, controller) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  const workerService = controller.services.workers;
  if (!workerService) {
    return res.json({
      ok: false,
      info: 'Worker service has not been started. Relaunch API server and check logs.'
    });
  }

  let commandObject = '';
  try {
    const postBody = req.body;
    // build a backtest execution command based on request params
    commandObject = getWorkerCommandFromPostBody(postBody);

  } catch (exception) {
    return res.json({
      ok: false,
      info: exception
    });
  }

  return controller.services.workers
    .promiseWorkerExecution(commandObject)
    .then(result => {
      if (result.context && result.context.results) {
        return res.end(result.context.results);
      }

      return res.end(result);
    })
    .catch(e => res.end(e));
}
```

This is where I'm confused. The main thread where my express process is running, does not get blocked. The whole intensive operation is delegated to a dedicated subprocess (via the "cluster" module).

However, if I trigger 3 of these requests, the 2nd request does not even start processing until the first request sees `res.end()`. It's purely waiting for a promise to resolve. I'm sure this can be reproduced with a promise waiting for a setTimeout to resolve a few seconds later.

Is this expected? I thought I could just treat this as async operations, and when i'm ready, this request response can be sent when the promise resolves.

Is there no way I can continue accepting parallel requests to the express server, without running a cluster on the express server too? I was hoping for one express server, and separate (capped) workers to delegate/handle the CPU intensive stuff.

I need to keep track of how many operations are running in parallel, so I wanted to ideally not have separate express services...does anyone have recommendations on handling this?

Edit: I should add I'm aware of the single threaded nature of Node, but I thought the fact promises allow parallel async ops as long as they don't block the thread...

Edit: I've reproduced the issue in a sandbox using only setTimeout to delay the res.send:

Hey everyone, so it is reproducible with setTimeout, which is clearly not a CPU intensive blocking task. Sandbox: 
https://codesandbox.io/embed/nr41lkw95j

I'm testing 3 parallel requests by triggering this in terminal: 
curl https://nr41lkw95j.sse.codesandbox.io/test && curl https://nr41lkw95j.sse.codesandbox.io/test && curl https://nr41lkw95j.sse.codesandbox.io/test

The terminal on the sandbox server shows it's blocking request processing until the current request sends a response, even if things are happening in an async callback

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191287/discussion-on-question-by-tiago-async-promise-blocking-nodejs-express-requests-u).

Comment: Answered your question, you were using the wrong command to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is how you're running the requests, that's not how you run requests in parallel.

```
curl https://nr41lkw95j.sse.codesandbox.io/test && curl https://nr41lkw95j.sse.codesandbox.io/test && curl https://nr41lkw95j.sse.codesandbox.io/test
```

When you use `&&` it waits until the last command was executed correctly without triggering an error to execute the next one. If you want to run requests in parallel you have to do the following:

```
curl https://nr41lkw95j.sse.codesandbox.io/test &
curl https://nr41lkw95j.sse.codesandbox.io/test &
curl https://nr41lkw95j.sse.codesandbox.io/test &
```

With a single `&`, so it runs in the background.

An alternative is to use apache benchmark, or similar programs.

```
ab -n 9 -c 3 https://nr41lkw95j.sse.codesandbox.io/test
```

The above command executes 9 requests in total, with a concurrency of 3.
Running it, you will see:

```
received request:  10
received request:  11
received request:  12
sent response:  10
sent response:  11
sent response:  12
received request:  13
received request:  14
received request:  15
sent response:  13
sent response:  14
sent response:  15
received request:  16
received request:  17
received request:  18
sent response:  16
sent response:  17
sent response:  18
```

Which is demonstrate that the Node.js can handle multiple requests concurrently, unless you block the event loop.

Comment: You're welcome :). That's the reason I asked you the exact command yesterday, because I figured you were either running it in the browser which limits concurrent requests, or your command wasn't correct :). But don't worry, that's how we learn, from our mistakes!. Now you know that Node.js can handle concurrency without any issue.

Comment: That's what got me stuck in this, I've been doing concurrency in node for a while now. It's only express that's gotten me stuck with a concurrency block, which didn't make sense to me as a single outlier - especially if there's no thread blocking. Really appreciate the help. Definitely part of the learning process :)